# Minimum cost of swapping chars in string so no 3 same are consecutive

Tags: string, algorithm, optimization, minimize, minimization

I have a string containing only two char values: `'a'` or `'b'`. A char can be swapped in for the other char value. Each char in the string has an associated cost with swapping it. I need to find the minimum cost of swaps such that there are no 3 consecutive chars with the same value in the resulting string.

If we have a block of consecutive chars with length 3, then we just swap the minimum cost char. If we have a block greater than length 3, then we have a number of possibilities for swaps. I don't know how to handle this case. How can I decide which chars to swap in a block greater than length 3 efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve this in `O(6n) = O(n)` time and `O(1)` space with [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Let `dp[i][state]` represent the best cost up to and including the `i`th character, when the last three characters are one of six valid `state`s (i.e., `aab`, `aba`, `baa`, `bba`, `bab`, `abb`). Then for `i > 2`:

```
dp[i][aab] ->
  if s[i] == "a":
    cost[i] + dp[i-1][baa]
  else:
    dp[i-1][baa]

dp[i][aba] ->
  if s[i] == "a":
    min(dp[i-1][aab], dp[i-1][bab])
  else:
    cost[i]+ min(dp[i-1][aab], dp[i-1][bab])

... (left as an exercise)
```